# Converting a Java program with main method into a servlet

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I am new to servlets. I have a query processor java program and now, I want to use it in a Web Application. I have an interface(HTML) which generates the query and I want to run the program on a button click in the interface. For this, I want to convert the java program into a java servlet. I am working in Net Beans.

Following is the structure of my Java program   :

```
public class ABC
{
  //code
  public ABC() //constructor
  {
   //code
  }
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   //code
  }
}
```

I want to convert this into a servlet. Following is the structure of a default servlet in Net Beans.

```
public class Demo extends Httpservlet
{
 /*----
  ----
  ----
  ----*/
 public void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, Httpservlet response) 
 throws ServletException,IOException
 {
  /*code*/
 }
 /*HttpServlet methods - doGet(), doSet() etc.*/
}
```

Is there any alternative for the main function in the servlet? Which method is executed first when the sevlet starts running? Can I run the Java Program on a button click on a HTML page so that I can eliminate the use of servlet?

Comment: You probably need to write your main method contents in either doGet or doPost method. Or you may invoke the main method from those do* methods directly. If you are not sure what these do* methods are, then you will have to read about servlets a bit first

Comment: There is no main method in servlet. What do you mean by invoking the main method from the do* methods? @Hirak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `get` or `post` method in servlet depend on your action. There are `doGet` , `doPost` and so many HTTP methods you need to determine in which you write code

Answer (score 0):

To use your query processor on the web you will have to build a Java Web Application.
Try the tutorial below and then call your ABC class from a Servlet.

[Introduction to Developing Web Applications](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps.html)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Dynamic web project, add new servlet usee doGet method or doPost method refer this link for the same.

[servlet example](http://www.studytonight.com/servlet/creating-servlet-in-eclipse.php)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please have in mind that the purpose of use is different in those two cases. While the `main` method of a class is invoked when you compile and run it as part of an application (run on a machine), the `doGet` and `doPost` methods are invoked in a servlet after a GET/POST request is made by client side to the server side, on which the Servlet lives.

On the first case, usually everything occurs on a specified machine, following the logic "*do something, then done*", and on the second case, you have a Request/Response Model between Clients and a Server (following the logic "*do something when **asked**, then **wait** for being asked again*"). You need to have a Server (e.g. Tomcat) set up to use the servlets.